# remove following: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_img.empty() in function 'cv::imwrite'

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to extract the silhouettes from video by below python code but after extraction, at last point, I am getting the following error:

cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.2) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\loadsave.cpp:715: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_img.empty() in function 'cv::imwrite'

how to remove this error.

Python code is:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('E:\\DCIM_with_two_cycle\\In_Lab\\021\\MVI_0098.MP4')
fgbg = cv2.bgsegm.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG()
count = 0;
while 1:
    count = count + 1
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    fgmask = fgbg.apply(frame)
    # cv2.imshow('frame', fgmask)
    if count < 10:
        cv2.imwrite('E:\\DCIM_with_two_cycle\\In_LabSilhoutte\\image000' + str(count) + '.jpg', fgmask)
    elif count < 100:
        cv2.imwrite('E:\\DCIM_with_two_cycle\\In_LabSilhoutte\\image00' + str(count) + '.jpg', fgmask)
    elif count < 1000:
        cv2.imwrite('E:\\DCIM_with_two_cycle\\In_LabSilhoutte\\image0' + str(count) + '.jpg', fgmask)
    elif count < 10000:
        cv2.imwrite('E:\\DCIM_with_two_cycle\\In_LabSilhoutte\\image' + str(count) + '.jpg', fgmask)
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break
cap.release()
#cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: What research have you done? Undoubtedly you found several questions on Stack Overflow with this exact error. Did the answers on those questions not help you?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I resolved this by following code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('E:\\DCIM_with_two_cycle\\In_Lab\\021\\MVI_0098.MP4')
fgbg = cv2.bgsegm.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG()
count = 0;
while 1:
    count = count + 1
    print(count)
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    fgmask = fgbg.apply(frame)
    # cv2.imshow('frame', fgmask)
    print((fgmask is None) == True)
    if (fgmask is None) == False:
        if count < 10:
            cv2.imwrite('E:\\DCIM_with_two_cycle\\In_LabSilhoutte\\image000' + str(count) + '.jpg', fgmask)
        elif count < 100:
            cv2.imwrite('E:\\DCIM_with_two_cycle\\In_LabSilhoutte\\image00' + str(count) + '.jpg', fgmask)
        elif count < 1000:
            cv2.imwrite('E:\\DCIM_with_two_cycle\\In_LabSilhoutte\\image0' + str(count) + '.jpg', fgmask)
        elif count < 10000:
            cv2.imwrite('E:\\DCIM_with_two_cycle\\In_LabSilhoutte\\image' + str(count) + '.jpg', fgmask)
    else:
        break
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break
cap.release()
# cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Explain what the problem was and what you did to fix it.  A "code dump" with no explanation is not helpful to other people.

Comment: a short explanation of your solution would help others understand the problem much better